# How to trigger a Rules action based on which content pane of a panel is used?

Tags: views, rules

I have a page with a path like `www.example.com/newsroom`. On this page nodes are displayed with help of **2 different views**:

1. View 1 : contains voted nodes by user.
2. View 2 : contains not voted nodes by user.

The 2 views are **content panes** and `www.example.com/newsroom` is a panel page. So there is no difference in the path of both views, and the user can see both views together.

I am using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to perform some action when vote is cast on any of node. And using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) one can check the path from where a user performs an action on a node, simply by using the token `[site:current-page:url]`. But  in my case that is `www.example.com/newsroom` (no matter where the vote is related to).

Is there any way that I can differentiate if a node on that page is voted from via View 1 or View 2? As `[site:current-page:url]` returns path `www.example.com/newsroom` ... Based on which view it is, I want [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to perform different actions. So how to check in Rules if the node being voted on is from View 1 or View 2?

I do have different classes of both views, but I'm not sure how to check those with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried to further enhance (condense) you question, mostly by removing duplicate stuff in it. Please review/double check it (again), to make sure I didn't make any mistakes or cleaned it up too much. Where needed edit your question again. I think you should also add the tag "7" to it. PS: I doubt it'll get any more close votes now ... Hopefully some extra upvotes ... I find it a very interesting question (= challenge)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Rules panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_panes) module. Some details about it (from its project page):

> Rules Panes allow embedding Rules components as content panes in Panels (or so).
>
> By default any parameters for the component are entered manually by the end user, but they can also be pre-populated with CTools contexts on the page (which will also hide the form input).

So if you can find a way to transform your "*... rules to perform some action ...*" in a Rules component, you should be good to go.

Some pointers to some more docu/demos about it (also mentioned on its project page):

- [Videos introducing this module](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5sq4vtv3sTHUpeR_f6r7WwDEcxPbYtw4).
- [Presentation from DrupalCamp Stockholm 2013](http://drupal.org/node/1931906).
- [Video about Rules panes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-DnQwrHJdM).

Comment: Thank you :) for your all help and understanding my question and pointing towards right direction  !!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback (and "accept ...). I'd be interested in getting some more details about how my "pointer" helped you to get it to work. Maybe you want to ADD your own answer also, something like "using the hint about 'Rues panes',  this is how I got it to work, and this is how my exported Rule looks like". I bet it would be upvoted! If you want to do so: hurry (before your question eventually gets put on hold). PS: I voted against closing your question. And with my edits of your question, I hope the current close counter (= 3) will not increase anymore ...

Comment: Thanks for spending more time and efforts and clearing up things. Frankly speaking I haven't accomplished it  yet but I am going thorough videos etc and it seems it can solve problem. I did accept as for efforts but if this is confusing other users and close votes are coming. Please guide me what to do with this situation. Do I un-accept it until I am not solve this completely. But as far I can tell you changed title this is what exactly I am trying.  Please let me know what I am supposed to do now with answer

Comment: Thank you again for your efforts and time. I am working and hopefully will try to provide updates as soon I will be done hopefully. But I think for current situation at least you understood question and pointed towards using module and trying solution.

Comment: OK for me. If some day you add another "answer" to this question here, then please let me know about it via another comment to my answer here (so that I get notified about it). For now: au revoir!